# Change the character set of a file when extracting a zip

Tags: perl, character-encoding, zip

I have a zip file that I'm trying to decompress; there's a file inside it
that has an encoded (I think UTF8?) filename and instead of "ímynd.dd" it's changing the name to "Ã­mynd.dd"

this is my code:

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
my $testsArchive = "master.zip";
my $testsDirectory = "master/";
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
die 'read error' unless ( $zip->read( $testsArchive ) == AZ_OK );
$zip->extractTree( '', $testsDirectory );
```

You can download the zip file from here:
https://github.com/log2timeline/dfvfs/archive/master.zip

I'm using version 1.57 of the library, on win7, perl 5.22.1.
If I run the same code on OS X it works file, so it has something to do with the charset encoding on Windows, but I'm at a loss how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From cpan.org

```
$Archive::Zip::UNICODE
```

This variable governs how Unicode file and directory names are added to or extracted from an archive. If set, file and directory names are considered to be UTF-8 encoded. This is EXPERIMENTAL AND BUGGY (there are some edge cases on Win32). Please report problems.

```
    {
        local $Archive::Zip::UNICODE = 1;
        $zip->addFile('Déjà vu.txt');
    }
```

link:[cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.57/lib/Archive/Zip.pm)

Comment: Thanks, I've given that a go in the past and it half works. It extracts the file, but throws an error and crashes. I'm not sure if that's to do with the reported bugs or my code.